# The component is reset when I move to another page. Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

In the component I upload the file and send it to the server.

```
export class SignalsComponent {


  selectedFile: File = null;
  addFileStatus = false;
  progressBar: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpService) {}


  onFileSelected(event) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    this.addFileStatus = true;
  }

  sendCsvFile() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('csv-file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.postData(formData);
    this.http.progressBar.subscribe((data) => {
      this.progressBar = data;
    });
  }

}
```

The post method is rendered in a separate service. The file goes to the server and immediately returns in json. In the service, I subscribe to the file using Subject.

```
postData(data: any) {
      return this.http.post('/upload_csv/', data, {
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events'
      })
        .subscribe(data => {
          if(data.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            this.progress.next('Progress upload: ' + Math.round(data.loaded / data.total * 100) + '%');
          } else if (data.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            this._dataChanged.next(data.body);
          }
        });
    }
```

And bring out json in other components in the tables. One of the tables is on one page with the component in which I send the file to the server. The data is output in this table good. It`s component.ts of my table:

```
constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

  signals: SignalList[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.onDataChanged.subscribe((data) => {
      this.signals = data;
      console.log(this.signals);
    });
  }
```

It`s html of my table:

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let signal of signals | paginate: { itemsPerPage:6, currentPage: p }">
          <th><small class="font-weight-bold">{{signal?.exchange}}</small></th>
          <td><small class="font-weight-bold">{{signal?.coin}}</small></td>
          <td><small class="font-weight-bold">{{signal?.base}}</small></td>
          <td><small class="font-weight-bold">{{signal?.tstamp | formatDate}}</small></td>
          <td><small>{{signal?.highest}}</small></td>
          <td><small>{{signal?.lowest}}</small></td>
          <td><small>{{signal?.m30}}</small></td>
          <td><small>{{signal?.h1}}</small></td>
          <td><small>{{signal?.h3}}</small></td>
          <td><small>{{signal?.h6}}</small></td>
          <td><small>{{signal?.h12}}</small></td>
          <td><small>{{signal?.h24}}</small></td>
          <td><small></small></td>
          <td><small>{{signal?.buy_price}}</small></td>
          <td><small></small></td>
          <td><small></small></td>
          <td><small></small></td>
          <td><small></small></td>
          <td><small></small></td>
          <td><small></small></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p=$event"></pagination-controls>
```

Other tables are on other pages. As soon as I follow to the link to another page all the data in the tables is cleared. Because the component through which I uploaded the file to the server is reset. How do I make the component not be reset?

P.S. I`ve solved this problem. Instead of the Subject() should use a ReplaySubject().

Comment: Please provide the interesting code snippets. Just hipshooting I'd say you need another service in which you then put your JSON-Response. But without seeing your code it's just a surmise.

Comment: Please read [ask] and then create a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show the HTML and .component.ts of your tables?

Comment: I edited my question. And added html and component.ts of my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve solved this problem. Instead of the Subject() should use a ReplaySubject().

Answer (score 0):

After returning json-data It must save to data-base. 
Your tables can read data (about files) from DB. 
Your service needs method GET for getting data after updating page or routing.
For reading data you must save it to anywhere. Usually this place is DB.